# Apache mod_lua enabled, PHP class LUA not found

Tags: php, apache, lua, debian

I've, somehow, managed to play with LUA on my local machine (Windows). Now I tried to put that on my dev server (**Debian 9** with **Apache 2.4.25** with **PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u1** and **Lua 5.3.3**).

After hours, dozens of errors and thousands of StackOverflow's pages read, I have finally been able to manually compile and build *PECL lua-2.0.5* and successfully made apache module.

I used `$ a2enmod lua`. Now, on `phpinfo()` I see `mod_lua` along others `Loaded Modules`.

I can run lua scripts from cli. No problem here.

I can't use lua from PHP scripts:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Lua' not found in [...]
```

I can't use lua through Apache as well (through `http://domain/path/to.lua`), even after editing `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` with new lines:

```
LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
<Files "*.lua">
    SetHandler lua-script
</Files>
```

None of the 4 line made any noticeable difference.

Running Lua scripts directly through Apache (from URL) is optional. But I really need to be able to interpret Lua from my PHP scripts. But even with `mod_lua` displayed in `Loaded Modules` in `phpinfo()`, PHP can't find class `Lua`. Why?

Comment: maybe you need a php extension also. I found this script look at line 28+ it downloads and builds a php extension https://github.com/chtombleson/php-lua-install-script/blob/master/install.sh

Comment: @aloMalbarez that's what I've done with `PECL lua-2.0.5` and `Lua 5.3.3` from `aptitude`, but all it did was making apache module. It is seen by PHP in `phpinfo()`, but still, no `Lua` class :/

Comment: and its listed as extension in the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` ? or its conf.d own ini? tried to install lua via pecl but found some errors, but I remember that some extensions that use apache mods also needs you to explicity set the php.ini option

Comment: @aloMalbarez oh, I feel dumb. Yes, you are right. I've added `extension=lua.so` to main `php.ini` and it works now. Post an answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the extension it has to be enabled, some install scriptss do it for you.

depending on your OS the php.ini to do it could vary in mine (ubuntu 16) are

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/CLI/php.ini
```

if it has multiple config options you can/should make a dedicated extensionname.ini under `/etc/php/7.0/{CLI|apache2}/conf.d`

shortcut from commandline

```
$ php -dextension=/path/to/extension.so
```

or

```
$ phpenmod extensionname
```

this one can be found as `php5enmod` for php5

edit: in your case as you noticed the line to add to the .ini is `extension=lua.so`